# Syntactic function of "what" in specific case

Tags: syntactic-analysis

See the following sentence:

> Be careful what you eat.

In this case, "what" is having which syntactic function? I checked the possibilities in the wiktionary:
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what
My best guess is that it is a "relative pronoun", but I'm not 100% convinced of that. I feel it could be something other than a pronoun, although I'm not sure how to support that.

(second question removed by OP to keep the focus)

Comment: People in this specific stackexchange are really fond of downvoting questions... :-/

Comment: Please have a look at our [about] page which describes the scope of the site. As for downvotes, you have one. That means that one person decided to downvote, hardly enough to reach conclusions about the entire site :). Also, you may be interested in our sister site, [ell.se]. Oh and asking multiple questions in one is [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/203101) on all sites of the SE network.

Comment: I did read the about, my question seemed to follow what's in the section "Get answers to practical, detailed questions". I even got a badge for reading the whole about! :D I got my conclusion about downvotes when I saw that in the "related" box 4 of 10 questions were below zero. :-/ About the sister site, I'm currently reading this to see if I get to any conclusion: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/posing-an-ell-like-question-on-elu?cb=1 Thanks for the feedback so far. :)

Comment: Well, those downvotes might be a hint :). The second part of your question is really off topic because it is very simple to a native speaker. It is, understandably, hard for someone who is not, but that's what [ell.se] is for.

Comment: Removed the second part. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Be careful what you eat*, the word *what* is a pronoun. Specifically, it is a relative pronoun. There is a very similar example on the wiktionary [page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what) you linked to:

> 4 (relative) That which; those that; the thing that.
>
> *he knows what he wants;  what is tossed upward falls back down*